# добавление ресурсов в jar файл

Tags: java, jar, resources

Господа знатоки подскажите... При запуске приложения в среде - приложение подтягивает все картинки, иконки и т.д. все как положено, все отрабатывает на все 100%. Но при сборке в jar картинки не подтягиваются. Сбор не мавеном. Подскажите куда копать. Можно ли где то в среде указывать папку с ресурсами или где по коду? Среда IDEA.

Comment: Собираете с помощью gradle?

Comment: Project Structure -> Artifacts->+->показываю main class->Ok   затем     Build->Build Artifacts->Build 
Собственно JARник запускается - все работает, но в консоли пишет "Error loading image: тут путь блабла" и не подтягивает имэджи. Если начинаю как то менять путь прямо в коде то ругается сама среда.

Comment: Каким образом ресурсы (картинки) сложены при сборке? Будет лучше если иерархию покажете. Плюс каким именно образом вы пытаетесь получить доступ к ресурсам? Имеется ввиду код.